# Black transparent overlay on image hover with only CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a transparent black overlay to an image whenever the mouse is hovering over the image with only CSS.  Is this possible?  I tried this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zf5am/565/

But I can't get the div to show up.

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="overlay" />
</div> 

.image {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.image img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 200;
}
.overlay:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: did you mean to put :hover on the image div, not the overlay div?

Comment: Just a note: why are you putting such a high Z-index on the overlay? Z-indexes are not global; there is no need to 'hack' a high or low value to make them work.

Comment: This is what finally helped me to solve this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/4Dfpm/ No overlay div necessary. The image gets less opacity on hover, the div below should have a black background, voila.

Answer (score 242, accepted):

I'd suggest using a pseudo element in place of the overlay element. Because pseudo elements can't be added on enclosed `img` elements, you would still need to wrap the `img` element though.

[**LIVE EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9z26ky19/) -- [**EXAMPLE WITH TEXT**](http://jsfiddle.net/51csqs0b/)

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjsbh.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

As for the CSS, set **optional dimensions** on the `.image` element, and relatively position it. If you are aiming for a responsive image, just omit the dimensions and this will still work [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/s6q288sw/). It's just worth noting that the dimensions must be on the parent element as opposed to the `img` element itself, [see](http://jsfiddle.net/qhamuv32/).

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Give the child `img` element a width of `100%` of the parent and add `vertical-align:top` to fix the default baseline alignment issues.

```
.image img {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

As for the pseudo element, set a content value and absolutely position it relative to the `.image` element. A width/height of `100%` will ensure that this works with varying `img` dimensions. If you want to transition the element, set an opacity of `0` and add the transition properties/values.

```
.image:after {
    content: '\A';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}
```

Use an opacity of `1` when hovering over the pseudo element in order to facilitate the transition:

```
.image:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[**END RESULT HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9z26ky19/)

---

### If you want to add text on hover:

For the simplest approach, just add the text as the pseudo element's `content` value:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jdL7q7z1/)

```
.image:after {
    content: 'Here is some text..';
    color: #fff;

    /* Other styling.. */
}
```

That *should* work in most instances; however, if you have more than one `img` element, you might not want the same text to appear on hover. You could therefore set the text in a `data-*` attribute and therefore have unique text for every `img` element.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/avz0hgjs/)

```
.image:after {
    content: attr(data-content);
    color: #fff;
}
```

With a `content` value of `attr(data-content)`, the pseudo element adds the text from the `.image` element's `data-content` attribute:

```
<div data-content="Text added on hover" class="image">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjsbh.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

You can add some styling and do something like this:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/51csqs0b/)

In the above example, the `:after` pseudo element serves as the black overlay, while the `:before` pseudo element is the caption/text. Since the elements are independent of each other, you can use separate styling for more optimal positioning.

```
.image:after, .image:before {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.image:after {
    content: '\A';
    width: 100%; height:100%;
    top: 0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.image:before {
    content: attr(data-content);
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #f00;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.image:hover:after, .image:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh.  I like this version best.  What would you do if you wanted to display some white text on top of that transparent blackness?  Would you add another div and apply opacity to that separately?

Comment: Yeah, only on hover actually.

Comment: thanks this is a better solution then the one i had tried before

Comment: How I can set the caption to the center of the image?  `top:30%` works, [see my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fgnd/2075/), but for a responsive layout it would be nice to set it to the exact center. BTW: Thanks for this nice annswer.

Comment: @poor Here is one responsive approach [(updated example)](http://jsfiddle.net/e8t2gcxg/).. it uses `top: 50%`/`transform: translateY(-50%)` for vertical centering. It is one of the approach mentioned in this other answer if mine - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block/25799339#25799339

Comment: Hi, can you explain what is the `\A` there?

Comment: Nice approach thanks, but its not responsive actually I have used your code to make dark overlay cover for my cover image but if I give height:auto its not working can you please provide me short note @JoshCrozier

Answer (score 63):

#### [CSS3 filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

Although this feature is only implemented in webkit, and it doesn't have [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters), but It's worth taking a look at:

```
.image img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: .2s all;
}

.image img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/Zf5am/577/)**

#### References

- https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/filters/index.html
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter
- http://davidwalsh.name/css-filters
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/say-hello-to-css3-filters/

#### Similar topics on SO

- [How to Decrease Image Brightness in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535392/how-to-decrease-image-brightness-in-css)
- [Convert an image to grayscale in HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609273/convert-an-image-to-grayscale-in-html-css)
- [Defined Edges With CSS3 Filter Blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224320/defined-edges-with-css3-filter-blur)

Comment: Since release of FF35, FF does also support filters: http://jsfiddle.net/Zf5am/1766/.

Comment: dude!! awesome solution!!

Comment: How simple is this !

Comment: It should be noted that `filter` now seems to be accepted on most browsers, according to this page: https://caniuse.com/?search=-webkit-filter.

Answer (score 12):

You were close. This will work:

```
.image { position: relative; border: 1px solid black; width: 200px; height: 200px; }
.image img { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }
.overlay { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right:0; bottom:0; display: none; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }
.image:hover .overlay { display: block; }
```

You needed to put the `:hover` on image, and make the `.overlay` cover the whole image by adding `right:0;` and `bottom:0`.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zf5am/569/

Comment: I would also suggest using CSS3 animations for a slightly smoother transition for compliant browsers (IE users will just have to suffer).

Answer (score 7):

Here's a good way using :after on the image div, instead of the extra overlay div: http://jsfiddle.net/Zf5am/576/

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

.image {position:relative; border:1px solid black; width:200px; height:200px;}
.image img {max-width:100%; max-height:100%;}
.image:hover:after {content:""; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
```

Answer (score 2):

`.overlay` didn't have a height or width and no content, and you can't hover over `display:none`.

I instead gave the div the same size and position as `.image` and changes `RGBA` value on hover.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zf5am/566/

```
.image { position: absolute; border: 1px solid black; width: 200px; height: 200px; z-index:1;}
.image img { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }
.overlay { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; background:rgba(255,0,0,0); z-index: 200; width:200px; height:200px; }
.overlay:hover { background:rgba(255,0,0,.7); }
```

Answer (score 1):

See what I've done here: http://jsfiddle.net/dyarbrough93/c8wEC/

First off, you never set the dimensions of the overlay, meaning it wasn't showing up in the first place. Secondly, I recommend just changing the z-index of the overlay when you hover over the image. Change the opacity / color of the overlay to suit your needs.

```
.image { position: relative; width: 200px; height: 200px;}
.image img { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }
.overlay { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: gray; z-index: -10; width: 200px; height: 200px; opacity: 0.5}
.image:hover .overlay { z-index: 10}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by playing with the opacity of the image and setting the background color of the image to black. By making the image transparent, it will appear darker.

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image { position: relative; border: 1px solid black; width: 200px; height: 200px; background: black; }
.image img { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }
.image img:hover { opacity: .5 }
```

You might need to set the browser-specific opacity too to make this work in other browsers too.

Answer (score 0):

I would give a min-height and min-width to your overlay div of the size of the image, and change the background color on hover

```
.overlay { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;  z-index: 200; min-height:200px; min-width:200px; background-color: none;}
.overlay:hover { background-color: red;}
```