# Create an image overlay

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an image on a page and a div with info text [Code Pen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uabjI).

```
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/>
  <div class="info">
    <a href="#">GO</a>
    <span>Title</span>    
    <p>Some information text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like the div Info to be invisible and when I move the mouse over the image the div would show over the image, with a transparency, and exactly the same width and height of the image.

And I would like the anchor inside the div Info to be on the right up corner. How can I do this?

Comment: You forgot to post the CSS/jQuery you tried that didn't work.

Comment: Don't need jQuery... http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/TWBhU/

Comment: I didn't try JQuery because I am not sure if this can be made with CSS or if I need JQuery ... And to be honest I am not sure how to do this with JQuery.

Comment: I would definitely go with CSS for this. Pointless loading a big library for something as as small as this.

Comment: You don not need to load a big library, and I pretty much assume everyone who is developing on the web, is using jQeury specially when they tag the question with jQuery....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No jQuery needed.

You need to relatively position the parent element, `.overlay`. You could also change the display to `inline-block` if you want it to take the dimensions of the `img` element. Absolutely position the `.info` element to take the same size as the parent. Use a `rgba()` color for transparency. Use the selectors `.overlay img:hover + .info, .info:hover` to change the display of the `.info` element to `block` when hovering over the `img` and the `.info` element.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/aCnFs/)

```
.overlay {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
.info {
    display:none;
    background-color: rgba(240,240,240,0.5);
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; right:0;
    bottom:0; left:0;
}
.overlay img:hover + .info, .info:hover {
    display:block;
}
```

If you want the overlay to fade/transition, simply manipulate the element's `opacity` rather than changing the display. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ym9Jc/).

For a better, more detailed answer - see [**my other answer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322548/black-transparent-overlay-on-image-hover-with-only-css/18322705#18322705).

Comment: Nice answer. Didn't think of using CSS like that.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised so many answers resort to calculating.  More people need to sit down and try to understand CSS `position` attributes.

Comment: Yea, I admit that I am not 100% on CSS wit it. Though, I rarely touch it as much compared to C#.

Comment: I do not understand down voting jQuery answers though. Just leave it at 0.  People answer it how they see it, and you should only down vote if it is horrible...   They tagged it with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use jQuery, however it will **not** be the preferred choice:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".info").hover(function(){
         $(this).show();
     });
});
```

Or as @Josh has suggested, the simple CSS which will be faster and saves having to load a big library:

```
.overlay img:hover, .info:hover {
    display:block;
}
// Credits for this go to Josh Crozier
```

Do note though that `rgba` will not work in IE8 and below. Not sure if you're going to be supporting it but thought I would let you know never the less

Answer (score 0):

First you need to hide your div.info with CSS:

```
div.info { display:none }
```

Then with jQuery you need to create a function that detects when the mouse is hover the img:

```
function() {

    $("img").hover(function() {

          $(".info").css("display","block");
          $(".info").width($(img).width());
          //More things
    });
}
```

Comment: I would suggest making `$(".info")` a variable if you're calling it twice :)

Answer (score 0):

It could look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#yourdiv").mouseover(function(){
            //
        });
        $("#yourdiv").mouseout(function(){
            //
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.yourdiv{
    background-image: url(yourimg.jpg);
    height: 420px;
    width: 420px;
}
</style>
<div id="yourdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your details were a little vague on this request for help, also you didn't provide any attempts at your jquery, so basically I'm giving you the simplest form of what you're asking for.

Here is the [codepen](http://cdpn.io/BwHgu)

**Note**

CSS Reset in codepen was used, and the jquery library must be called in order for that to work in whatever you do.

Also, since this question was rather lazy I didn't provide you any IE fallbacks because I felt like being lazy :).

### HTML

```
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
    <div id="overlay" class="info">
      <a id="show-me" href="#">GO</a>
      <span>Title</span>    
      <p>Some information text</p>
        <div id="hidden-div">
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Content Here</p>
            <a id="close" href="#">&#x2716; Close Overlay!</a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

### CSS

```
*, 
*:before, 
*:after { 
box-sizing: border-box; 
}

body, 
html { 
margin: 1em; 
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

a:link { 
text-decoration: none; 
color: #DB1F1F; 
}

.info {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/400x200'); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover; 
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 200px; 
  width: 400px; 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 1; 
}

#hidden-div { 
 display: none; 

 position: absolute;
 height: 200px; 
 width: 400px; 
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 background: rgba(205,36,36,.5);
 display: none;
 z-index: 0
}

.content { 
position: relative; 
top: 50px; 
}

.content p { 
margin: .5em 0; 
color: #fafafa;
}

.content a:link, 
.content a:visited { 
color: #950000; 
font-weight: 700;
}
```

### JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#show-me").click(function(){ 
  $("#hidden-div").toggle("slow"); 
  });
  $("#close").click(function(){ 
  $("#hidden-div").toggle("fast");
  });
});
```