# How to make a transparent overlay on image

Tags: html, css

I have an simple image like this:

```
<img src="/assets/missing.png">
```

Now what I want is to be able to hover over the image and have a transparent black overlay appear with a big 'x' on it. Is it possible with CSS3 only or do I need Javascript? And if so how?

---

I sort of got it to work, but i have an issue that i can't seem to fix. Here's a screenshot:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9S2QF.png)

As you can see there is a part on top missing. Here is my css:

```
.image {
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  margin: 15px;
  position:relative;
}

.image img {
  width:100%;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.image:after {
  content:'\A';
  position:absolute;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  top:0; left:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  opacity:0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.image:hover:after {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: This is very possible with CSS :) Here is a duplicate question - [Black transparent overlay on image hover with only CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18322548/2930477)

Comment: @misterManSam Thanks it worked more or less but i still have an issue (check question edits). Any ideas where the problem is?

Comment: Make sure that the max height and width match the image dimensions. That said, [I have optimised this version](http://jsfiddle.net/0b6tau0r/) by combining some answers. How does that work for  you when you change the max image width and height for your image?

Comment: @misterManSam I figured it out, was just a padding issue. Thanks for the help :) Cheers

Comment: No worries, just for the heck of it, [this version does not require a height and width](http://jsfiddle.net/0b6tau0r/1/). Sitenote: Please only accept an answer that was helpful to you... you don't need to accept any answer - especially if you received most guidance through that other question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at following fiddle. I hope it can help.
http://jsfiddle.net/somy_taheri/93y6hwjk/1/

```
<html>
    <div class="outer">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300">                    
            <div class="overlay">
                <p class="text">x</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</html>
<style>
.outer {
    position:relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}
.overlay {                      
    display: none;  
}

.outer:hover .overlay { 
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    top: 0;
}
.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    color:white;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this.

HTML :

```
<div class="div">
    <div class='overlay'><p>X</p></div>
    <img src="http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2012/157/c/a/watch_dogs___wallpaper__2_by_danielskrzypon-d52hvi1.png"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div{
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
}
img{
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
}
.overlay{
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    position:absolute;
    background:rgba(0,153,255,.8);
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
}
.overlay p{
    color:white;
    line-height:400px;
    font-size:80px;
    margin:0;
}
```

Query:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".div").stop().mouseenter(function(){
        $(".overlay").fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $(".div").stop().mouseleave(function(){
        $(".overlay").fadeOut('slow');
    });
})
```

Take a look. JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/u5ka7Lq4/19/