# How to make this image blur with transparent dark background

Tags: html, image, css, blur

I want to implement the image like below image with css. I mean i want to make the image background appear but in front the image should be transparent. I mean it should be covered like blur. I want to achieve like below image.

[image]

```css
img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
-moz-filter: blur(5px);
-o-filter: blur(5px);
-ms-filter: blur(5px);
filter: blur(5px);
position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/v06GqMK.jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: @Kode.Error404 i added but the image i want to achieve like above image my image is turning to more blur

Comment: @HosseinMaktoobian yeah like above image i want to achieve.......

Comment: try the filter like this: `filter: blur(1px) brightness(0.5);`. this will darken your image.

Comment: If you are looking for an overlay then you could refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322548/black-transparent-overlay-on-image-hover-with-only-css

Comment: Thanks for your precious suggestions it solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS pseudo element or other html element to achieve this.
Here's an example using the pseudo element :before

```css
.blur {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block; /* make the div not 100% */
}
/* the 'blur' effect */
.blur:before {
  content: '';
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.blur img {
  display: block; /* remove bottom space */
}
```

```html
<div class="blur">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/v06GqMK.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

this Is What You Want:

```css
.container {
  background: url("https://d36ai2hkxl16us.cloudfront.net/thoughtindustries/image/upload/a_exif,c_fill,w_750,h_361/v1426633725/eq54w9myfn6xfd28p92g.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 750px;
  height: 361px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.container::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px) brightness(0.5);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px) brightness(0.5);
  -ms-filter: blur(1px) brightness(0.5);
  -o-filter: blur(1px) brightness(0.5);
  filter: blur(1px) brightness(0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background: inherit;
  z-index: 0;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.title {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: gold;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 20px;
}

.text {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='title'>Content Marketing</div>
    <div class='text'>6 Essential Elements You Can't Ignore</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great work.Thanks. Small description: if someone want to remove padding for blur effect , decrease left top right bottom to 0.1px.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `linear-gradient()`

```
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50)), url('image.png');
```

Should do the trick. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.background {
  background: url(klematis.jpg) repeat;
  border: 2px solid black;
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  -moz-filter: blur(2px);
  -o-filter: blur(2px);
  -ms-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
}

div.transbox {
  margin: 0px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

div.transbox p {
  margin: 5%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div class="background">
    <div class="transbox">
      <p>This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```