# Background color change on hover not working along with CSS animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I had been trying to achieve the effect on [this page](https://www.beoplay.com/products/beoplayh8#usp) (it does not seem to work on some touchscreens!) where the text goes up and the background goes dark on hover, but I can't make the background change when I added the CSS animation, If I remove it then background color effect works well.

Also I would like to have this effect on 100% height of the background picture, as in the original page.

Is there a way I can make it work?

```css
#tech-specs-container-desk {
 display: inline-block; 
 position: relative;
 z-index : 1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 581px; 
 background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQF3B.jpg');
 background-size: 100vw 100%;  
 }
 .specs:hover{
 font-size: 25pt;
 line-height: 30pt;
 position: relative;   
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)   
  -webkit-animation: moving-spec 3s forwards;
 animation: moving-spec 3s forwards;   
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes moving-spec {
    from {bottom: 0px;}
    to {bottom: 100px;}
}

@keyframes moving-spec {
    from {bottom: 0px;}
    to {bottom: 100px;}
} 
 .specs{
 width: 18%;
 display: inline-block;   
 font-family:'Futura Std Light';
 font-size: 15pt;
 line-height: 20pt; 
 color: #666666;
 text-align: center; 
 padding: 10px 20px; 
 border-right: 0.5px solid #666666;
 vertical-align: text-top;   
 }
 #inner-specs-container-desk {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;    
 width: 100%;
 top:270px;   
 }
```

```html
<div id="tech-specs-container-desk">
    <div id="inner-specs-container-desk">
      <div id="spec-one" class="specs"> Integración con sistemas de salud bajo protocolo HL7 </div>
      <div id="spec-two" class="specs"> Funcionamiento en tiempo real</div>
      <div id="spec-three" class="specs">Almacenamiento en CLOUD y escalable </div>
      <div id="spec-four" class="specs">Protocolos de seguridad de la información </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Background img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQF3B.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Black transparent overlay on image hover with only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322548/black-transparent-overlay-on-image-hover-with-only-css)

Comment: I had seen this before, but how do I implement it in only a portion of the background picture, according to the text hovered and while maintaining the text animation.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I changed the css, used background before the animation+background, so it was defined properly. The background+animation is invalid in my browser.

edit: Below answer is correct. Didnt even see the missing symbol.

```css
#tech-specs-container-desk {
 display: inline-block; 
 position: relative;
 z-index : 1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 581px; 
 background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQF3B.jpg');
 background-size: 100vw 100%;  
 }
 .specs:hover{
 font-size: 25pt;
 line-height: 30pt;
 position: relative;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);   
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)   
  -webkit-animation: moving-spec 3s forwards;
 animation: moving-spec 3s forwards;
 z-index: 9999;   
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes moving-spec {
    from {bottom: 0px;}
    to {bottom: 100px;}
}

@keyframes moving-spec {
    from {bottom: 0px;}
    to {bottom: 100px;}
} 
 .specs{
 width: 18%;
 display: inline-block;   
 font-family:'Futura Std Light';
 font-size: 15pt;
 line-height: 20pt; 
 color: #666666;
 text-align: center; 
 padding: 10px 20px; 
 border-right: 0.5px solid #666666;
 vertical-align: text-top;   
 }
 #inner-specs-container-desk {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;    
 width: 100%;
 top:270px;   
 }
```

```html
<div id="tech-specs-container-desk">
    <div id="inner-specs-container-desk">
      <div id="spec-one" class="specs"> Integración con sistemas de salud bajo protocolo HL7 </div>
      <div id="spec-two" class="specs"> Funcionamiento en tiempo real</div>
      <div id="spec-three" class="specs">Almacenamiento en CLOUD y escalable </div>
      <div id="spec-four" class="specs">Protocolos de seguridad de la información </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing a `;` at the end of `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)`

Comment: Sorry I miss that, now how can I achieve the effect to 100% of the picture height?