# Filter brightness not working, CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to decrease the brightness of an image, and basically make it darker, and I'm trying to do it with filter: brightness, but for some reason the image is not getting darker at all. I started at 1%, and went all the way to 100%, but the image did not get darker at all. I don't know what I did wrong. Please take a look at my code:

```
img {
    filter: brightness(50%);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

<img src = 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/3164/sea-black-and-white-water-ocean.jpg'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, your browser does not support the spec out of the box. You should add a vendor prefix to get it to work in this case.

```
-webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
```

is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect. I'm using Google Chrome by the way.

Comment: Wow. Someone actually down-voted my question. I don't see what is wrong with it. It's a legit question.

Comment: I'm not responsible for the downvote, but obviously someone thought that not knowing about vendor prefixes was a mortal sin

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 10/8/2020**

It seems that CSS can easily understand both percentages and decimals as a percent in the brightness filter. Maybe this wasn't the case 5 years ago when I posted this answer originally, but it's certainly the case now.

Source/Documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

**Below is the original answer from 2015:**

---

Don't use percentages in the filter. It should be a scale from 0 to 1.

```
img {
    filter: brightness(0.5);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

0.5 would be equal to 50%

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

```
filter: brightness(0.4);     // Does not use percentage
filter: contrast(200%);      // Uses percentage
```

Comment: Isn't that the same thing as opacity then?

Comment: I'm trying to make it darker than what the image originally was like.

Comment: Someone with 34 upvotes on this question provided the answer filter: brightness(50%) with percentage instead of decimals. Source here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535392/how-to-decrease-image-brightness-in-css

Comment: According to the given link: `A value of 0% will create an image that is completely black. A value of 100% leaves the input unchanged.`. So this answer is plain wrong, at least if we take the given link as a source.

Comment: @XtremeBiker -- Good call. It seems that CSS can easily understand both percentages and decimals as a percent in the `brightness` filter. Maybe this wasn't the case 5 years ago when I posted this answer originally, but it's certainly the case now. Thanks for pointing that out!