# Light filter in css and html does not work

Tags: html, css

Hello and do not be tired

I use a light filter to darken the section tag

But this filter only works on the photo tag and does not work on the div tag

What am I really left to do?

‍‍‍

```html
<div style="filter: brightness(50%);" >
    <img src="./assets/images/logo_background.jpeg" width="70px"  alt="">
</div>
```

How can I apply the filter to all tags ??

Comment: Does this help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331512/filter-brightness-not-working-css

Comment: if your div has no styles (border, background, etc) the filter will do nothing