# Apply opacity to background image but not text

Tags: html, css, opacity

My problem is when I make my picture darker the text in class `.text` gets darker too, and I don't know how to avoid this.

I know one solution: to make `.wrap` `position:absolute` and class `.text` make not in `image` but this solution is unsuitable for me (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535392/how-to-decrease-image-brightness-in-css)).

Any other ideas?

This is the code that I have:

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
.image {
  background-image: url("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/1550273796/1372363601/1500x500");
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.8;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 350px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.text {
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="image">
    <div class="text">
      <p>I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE
        YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mqke05L0/5/)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`opacity` is not an `inherit` property but affect the content so when you increase the opacity of `.image` that also affects to `.text`, you can use pseudo elements and `background: rgba()` to achieve what you want like this:

Here a working [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/vjzmcm3z/) to play with

```css
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
}
.image {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1");
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}
.image:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.text {
    color: #FFF;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="image">
        <div class="text">
            <p>I LOVE YOU</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was testing that. Will that work with images? I thought only background colors.

Comment: Yes that only work with bg color but notice that the OP is trying to set opacity to the img to dark it with the black bg of `.wrap` so you can set a layer (pseudo element) over the img with a semitransparent bg and obtain the same result.

Comment: Worked perfekt! For real photos I added to .image: background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;  This will fir the image into the while container instead of repeating a pattern

Answer (score 4):

`opacity` is applied to the entire element (including the content).

Therefore,  because `div.text` is nested in `div.image`, the `opacity` applied to `div.image` applies to all descendants, as well.

With background colors you could apply the opacity directly to the property with `rgba()`:

```
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
```

... and the problem raised in your question is avoided.

However, with background images a workaround is needed.

Options include creating a separate `div` for the image or using a pseudo-element.

These options and a few others are detailed here:

- [Can I set an opacity only to the background image of a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241341/can-i-set-an-opacity-only-to-the-background-image-of-a-div)
- [CSS: set background image with opacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183948/css-set-background-image-with-opacity/)

Answer (score 1):

you could always apply webkit filters to make the text brighter

http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/qxtwckts/ or the following snippet http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/qxtwckts/1/

```css
#wrap {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-image: url("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/1550273796/1372363601/1500x500");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.9;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
#wrap:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
p {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">




  <div id="text">
    <p>I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE
      YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU
      <p>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to make it brighter , just normal color `FFF` but with darker background, but thx for answer

Comment: @tellmewhy... Happy it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

`opacity` is applied to the entire div rather fade the image instead of div using `linear-gradient()`

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
.image {
  background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgba(0,0,0,0.6)), url("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/1550273796/1372363601/1500x500");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 350px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.text {
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="image">
    <div class="text">
      <p>I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE
        YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU I LOVE YOU</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="background-image">
   <div id="text-color">
      Hello!!
   </div>
</div>
```

```css
.background-image {
  background-image: url(image.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  color:#fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.text-color { 
 background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```