# How to improve the contrast between background image and the text on it with css?

Tags: css

**Problem:**

I have developed an angular application there I am having a cover image in the home page. The code looks like this.

```
<div id="intro">
    <div class="intro-body">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-5">
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <h2>The hearth of the farm is the true center of our universe.</h2>
            <p class="intro-text">
              A full-service digital agency that loves what we do
            </p>
            <!-- <a href="#about" class="btn btn-default page-scroll">Learn More</a> -->
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my CSS file.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    #intro {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        height: 90%;
        padding: 100px 0;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        background: url(../../../assets/img/7.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;

        background-color: #000;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;

    }
    #intro .intro-body {

        vertical-align: auto;
    }
    #intro .intro-body H2 {
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin-left: -10% !important;
    }
    #intro .intro-body .brand-heading {
        color: #E75926;
        text-shadow: 0 4px #a13e1a;
    }
    #intro .intro-body .intro-text {
        font-size: 18px;
    }


}
```

This is how it is shown in the browser.

[image]

I want to make it like this.

[image]

Can someone help me to solve this matter by modifying my CSS? I tried a lot but I was unable to find what is the CSS property that I should change to do it. If you can help me it would be great. Thank you

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535392/how-to-decrease-image-brightness-in-css/11535482

Comment: Why are you using `display: table`? None of the children appear to be using a table layout?

Comment: @DanielHabenicht but It reduces the brightness of all content including the text inside the background image. How can I solve that?